# bitmap 'color' not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

### My Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(win, width = 50, height = 20)
txt.pack()

txt.insert('insert', 'Hello1\n')
txt.insert('insert', 'Hello2')
txt.tag_add('format1', '1.0', '1.5')
txt.tag_configure('format1', bg = 'blue')

win.mainloop()
```

### Error:

[image: output3]

The code above is similar to the one below because I took It as an example.

### Example code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
   pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, 'Hello.....')
text.insert(END, 'Bye Bye.....')
text.pack()

text.tag_add('here', '1.0', '1.4')
text.tag_add('start', '1.8', '1.13')
text.tag_configure('here', background = 'yellow', foreground = 'blue')
text.tag_configure('start', background = 'black', foreground = 'green')

win.mainloop()
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

### Question:

Where's the mistake in **my code**? As far as I'm concerned, `bg` option yields the error since, If we change its value, let's say red, we get:

[image: output2]

Comment: Sometimes tutorials have errors or typos in them. The mistake in your code, when you use `bg` instead of `background`, is that you should - evidently - use `background` instead. Like the working code from the tutorial. There isn't a question here that we can help you with. Consider [contacting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/contact_us.htm) tutorialspoint to report the error.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just wanted people who know, unlike me, to verify what I'm saying so others novices notice these subtleties.

Comment: `bg` is indeed a valid abbreviation for `background` when applied to *the widget itself*.  But that's not what you're doing here - you're configuring a tag, which has an entirely separate (although similar) set of options.  Here, `bg` is being interpreted as an abbreviation for `bgstipple`.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can post this sort of thing by answering your own question (and it's still a good idea to contact them).

Answer (score 1):

If we change `bg` to `background` in **my code**, we get:

[image: output3]

Note that options in `tk.Text` are not the same as the ones in `.tag_configure()` although similar. `bg` is not an abbreviation for `background` in `.tag_configure()` but for `bgstipple`, as *jasonharper* says in the comments.

Thus, what my source suggests is wrong:

[image: output4]

### Concluding remarks:

Same goes for `bd` and `fg` as they **are not** abbreviations for `borderwidth` and `foreground` respectively, unlike  `tk.Text`. I suggest being **explicit** when naming options if you don't know, like me, which ones could yield an error.